# Pylint in Sublime Text 2

Tags: plugins, sublimetext2, text-editor

So, I've been using Sublime for a while as a simple text editor, but I'm venturing into the land of plugins for work and I've run into an issue getting pylint to work. Specifically I have it installed and have the Sublime package manager working, but I'm not sure how to include paths in my sublime settings.

I haven't found very useful documentation on this point, but if you are willing to point me towards it that would be a perfectly acceptable answer. My basic issue is that currently every time I save a file, the following error message shows up:

`"Please define the full path to 'lint.py' in the settings"`

I understand this error message which is great, I just have no idea where the sublime settings are or what the standard format for defining a path is. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: which pylint plugin are you using? There are a few...

Comment: I am using SublimeLinter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are quite complete directions at the [SublimeLinter GitHub page](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter#readme) that should describe how to set everything up. Briefly, go to `Preferences->Package Settings->SublimeLinter->Settings - Default` to see where the different settings are defined. Then, open `Preferences->Package Settings->SublimeLinter->Settings - User` to change anything, as the main settings will be overwritten when the package is updated. Remember that settings files are in JSON format, so you'll need opening and closing curly brackets to enclose settings, and a comma between them:

```
{
    "sublimelinter_delay": 30,
    "sublimelinter_mark_style": "none"
}
```

I haven't gotten the error you have, are you sure you're using the regular SublimeLinter and not the new beta version? I just installed it fresh on my work machine (I've been using it for a while at home) and after restarting ST2 it's working like a charm with Python.

Comment: Oh huh, weird. I tried a clean install and it totally fixed the problem. Must have had some alternate version. Many thanks!

Comment: a fresh install cures all :)

Comment: if sublime doens't start anymore because of this error, open this file: C:\Users\{{user}}\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages\Pylinter\Pylinter.sublime-settings and add this path: "pylint_path": "C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/pylint/lint.py",

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. I found it to be coming from the package "Pylinter". I removed Pylinter and added SublimeLinter, it covers more than python and is well used. I'm enjoying it quite a bit.

Answer (score 2):

From your command line just run:

```
sudo easy_install pylint

sudo easy_install pep8
```

After that restart your sublime.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter the same situation today. In my case, that is because I have not installed the 'pylint' in my system yet. It works fine after I installed the 'pylint' through pip.
Just for other people reference.